# How to combine DataTables-component with MVC4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have a MVC4-project and want to use a DataTables-plugin (https://datatables.net) to create some items.

I render these items with html-helpers (EditorFor).

I'm using an add-button to add a new item to fill in. I made a jquery-function to copy the first line.

I also use the fnHeaderCallback-function to update the totals of the inputfields.

But How can I get the values of the datatable-inputfields?
(fnHeaderCallback gives me aaData, but I can not find the filled in values)